# page not responsive for few seconds after page load in IE 10 after changing jquery to 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I have changed the reference of jquery version to 3.1.1 from 1.4, now I am noticing performance issue on IE 10, in all other browsers it is coming properly.
Page loads correctly but when I click on any part of the page it hangs and respondds after 5 seconds.
Any help on how to debug such issue will be highly appreciated.
IE developer tools also do not give much details on why this issue is occuring.

Thanks
Sajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the issue, I was launching the application locally from Visual studio in debug mode and VS 2015 Browserlink was enabled by default because of which it was making the page slower, I disabled the feature and it is working perfectly, its weird i wasn't experiencing this performance issue before migration.